# Facebook dialog/feed not working for Pages

Tags: facebook

My problem is Facebook dialog feed URL is not posting when I use Facebook as one of my business page (from top right side dropdown). It gives 500 Internal Server Error. But when I switch to regular user (my personal account) it starts working. I also checked other popular sites (like cnn.com ) and they use dialog/share and that also doesn't work for Facebook pages and it forces you to switch as personal user. It was working a few days back.

For ref here is Dialog Feed URL

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=145634995501895
&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption 
&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```

Comment: This is working correctly now. Can you please confirm? Otherwise can you provide the URLs you're using to test?

Comment: It still doesn't work if you SWITCH to Pages.